# Can multiple threads copy a std::shared_future at the same time?

Tags: c++, multithreading, future

Is a shared_lock enough in GetNextImage(), or do I need to use a unique_lock?

```
shared_future<Mat> shfutNextImage;
shared_mutex shmutNextImage;

shared_future<Mat> GetNextImage()
{
    shared_lock lock(shmutNextImage);
    return shfutNextImage;
}

void SetNextImage(shared_future<Mat> shfut)
{
    unique_lock lock(shmutNextImage);
    shfutNextImage = shfut;
}
```

Comment: *Access to the same shared state from multiple threads is safe if each thread does it through its own copy of a shared_future object.* Line from [CppReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_future).

Comment: @kiner_shah So that means that it's not safe to copy the same shared_future from multiple threads?

Comment: What is your requirement? Calling GetNextImage from multiple threads?

Comment: @shared_future: Yes, calling from multiple threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `shfutNextImage` as an argument to the copy constructor from multiple threads is safe because the object is used as `const&` parameter, therefore you do not need a lock **assuming** no one modifies the object in the meantime -> shared/read lock is appropriate.

Assigning to `shfutNextImage` from multiple threads is not safe I think so the `unique_lock` is appropriate. At least I do not see any explicit mentions that it is thread-safe. Other non-const methods like `wait` are also not thread-safe.

Use `shfutNextImage = std::move(shfut);` if you can, to avoid unnecessary +1 (assignment), -1(destruction of shfut) to the reference counter. Copying shared futures is not cheap, you can image there is hidden `std::shared_ptr<State>` inside, so move is better.

Accessing the `Mat` object the future holds is never thread-safe, the protection is left to the user.